# how to save django object using dictionary?

Tags: django, django-models

is there a way that I can save the model by using dictionary

for e.g.
this is working fine,

```
p1 = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)

p1.name = 'poll2'
p1.descirption = 'poll2 description'

p1.save()
```

but what if I have dictionary like { 'name': 'poll2', 'description: 'poll2 description' }

is there a simple way to save the such dictionary direct to Poll

Answer (score 33, accepted):

drmegahertz's solution works if you're creating a new object from scratch. In your example, though, you seem to want to update an existing object. You do this by accessing the `__dict__` attribute that every Python object has:

```
p1.__dict__.update(mydatadict)
p1.save()
```

Comment: This can be very useful for upholding the DRY principle while doing tricky stuff on the `save()` method of `ModelForm`. For example, I have a a form that copies `cleaned_data` to a new dictionary, then deletes certain fields from it -- because values from other fields make them irrelevant or contradictory -- then saves only the remaining fields in that dictionary onto the instance (and the instance is an object that has already been initialized).

Answer (score 31):

You could unwrap the dictionary, making its keys and values act like named arguments:

```
data_dict = {'name': 'foo', 'description': 'bar'}

 # This becomes Poll(name='foo', description='bar')
 p = Poll(**data_dict)
 ...
 p.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

I find only this variant worked for me clear.
Also in this case all Signals will be triggered properly

```
p1 = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
values = { 'name': 'poll2', 'description': 'poll2 description' }        
for field, value in values.items():
    if hasattr(p1, field):
        setattr(p1, field, value)
p1.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update) on a filterset:

e.g.:

```py
data = { 'name': 'poll2', 'description: 'poll2 description' }
p1 = Poll.objects.filter(pk=1)
p1.update(**data)
```

**Notes:**

- be aware that `.update` does not trigger signals
- You may want to put a check in there to make sure that only 1 result is returned before updating (just to be on the safe side). e.g.: `if p1.count() == 1: ...`
- This may be a preferable option to using `__` methods such as `__dict__.`